# I am using Mobile Security Framework. When run python manage.py runserver, it displays this kind of error

Tags: python, security, mobile, frameworks

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x062BE630>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF-master\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 134, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named postgresql.base
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty self explanatory.

See:`No module named postgresql.base` 
Install postgresql, and configure it properly or use the default sqlite3 backend.